# Como criar um Banner de publicidade para o meu App ? Ionic e Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Quero criar um banner de publicidades de uma empresa no meu app no rodapé como eu faço alguém tem algum material que pode me explicar como fazer um banner para app.
tipo a imagem a baixo aonde está marcado a vermelho, como posso colocar igual no meu app ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: cara, sua pergunta não está tão clara, poderia especificar ela? Algum exemplo.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplar vÊ na imagem mano , sabe aquelas publicidades que passam em forma de slides no rodapé do app? é tipo isso que falo como colocar uma igual no meu app

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver se referindo a ferramentas de design para construir a arte do banner você pode usar:

• [Google Web Designer](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/) (específica)

• [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/br/products/photoshop.html) (não específica)

• Ou qualquer ferramenta de criação gráfica existente que desejar, ou procurar por **banner maker** online para usar uma das *(n)* opções online disponíveis

***Se a pergunta se refere a questão de frameworks e código para mostrar e monitorar os banners mostrados no App, recomendo editar a questão para deixa-la mais específica como o Marcos Henrique falou.***

Comment: Coloquei um exemplar vê na imagem mano , sabe aquelas publicidades que passam em forma de slides no rodapé do app? é tipo isso que falo como colocar uma igual no meu app.